# Redshift stored procedure having issue in while loop syntax error near "integer"

Tags: amazon-web-services, while-loop, amazon-redshift, with-statement

Working on Amazon Redshift stored procedure. Having issue in while loop syntax error near "integer"

```sql
create or replace procedure WHILE_COM(REC_COUNT INT)
AS $$ 
DECLARE 
     I INTEGER =1
     SET REC_COUNT=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
BEGIN
WHILE I<=REC_COUNT LOOP
      WITH FIRST_RECORD AS
              (SELECT * FROM ods_epremis.new_old_merge
               where new_old_merge.claim_oid IN(select TOP 1 claim_oid from ods_epremis.new_old_merge order by clain_oid)),
              MERGE_RECORD AS
               (SELECT * from ode_epremis.new_old_merge JOIN FIRST_RECORD
                   ON T1_accountno=T2_accountno)
             insert into targettable (select * from MERGE_RECORD)
            I=I+1
        END LOOP
  END
$$ LANGUANGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples from [Structure of PL/pgSQL - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-structure.html), variables should be set with `:=` rather than just `=`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_value() AS $$
DECLARE
  value integer := 20;
BEGIN
...
```

It also shows colons (`;`) at the end of commands.